# Can I get characteristic response in onCharacteristicRead() method instead of onCharacteristicChanged()

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am unable to handle multiple characteristic data in the form of notification in onCharacteristicChanged() method. Can we get the same data in `onCharacteristicRead()` method?

In my case, there are 9 characteristics and 6,7,8 is a notification characteristic firstly we have to notify these all (6,7,8) characteristics.
after that, I get value 1 in 6, 7, 8 characteristic. And then I have written text value in characteristic 1 again characteristic 6 notify and get value 3. After that, I write a Unicode value in characteristic 3 then we have got 2 in the form of notification in characteristic 6. In this scenario, all value comes in form notification. How can I handle for the same procedure for 4,5 in `onCharacteristicChanged()`?
I am also sharing onCharacteristicChanged() method code below and activity handling code for better understanding.

onCharacteristicChanged() method code -

```
@Override
        public void onCharacteristicChanged(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic) {
            super.onCharacteristicChanged(gatt, characteristic);
            byte[] messageBytes = characteristic.getValue();
            String messageString = null;
            try {
                messageString = new String(messageBytes);
                String hexvalue =toHex(messageString);
                RemoveZeroFromString removeZeroFromString = new RemoveZeroFromString(mContext);
                String firstValue =  removeZeroFromString.removeLeadingZeroes(hexvalue);
                String secondValue = removeZeroFromString.removeTrailingZeroes(firstValue);
                int bleResponce = Integer.parseInt(secondValue);
                GlobalVariable.bleStatus = bleResponce;
   } catch (Exception e) {
                DebugLogUtil.log(Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace(), e.getMessage());
            }

        }
```

And activity code where I handle all these notification values -

```
 @Override
    public void onStartButtonClick() {
        try {

            mButtonStart1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    switch (mButtonStart1.getTag().toString()) {
                        case Constants.BLE_START:
                            if (mConnGatt != null) {
                                GlobalVariable.bleStatus = 0;
                                mConnGatt.setCharacteristicNotification(characteristic_6, true);
                                BluetoothGattDescriptor descriptor = characteristic_6.getDescriptor(UUID.fromString(BleUuid.DESCRIPTOR_CONFIG_UUID));
                                descriptor.setValue(BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_NOTIFICATION_VALUE);
                                mConnGatt.writeDescriptor(descriptor);
                                new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void run() {
                                        if (GlobalVariable.bleStatus == 1) {
                                            System.out.println("***button click*****" + GlobalVariable.bleStatus);

                                            mChargingConnectionPresenter.startCharging(mConnGatt, characteristic_1, getString(R.string.dialog_title_ble_authentication), getString(R.string.dialog_message_ble_authentication), true, 1, true);

                                        } else if (GlobalVariable.bleStatus == 4) {
                                            mChargingConnectionPresenter.startCharging(mConnGatt, characteristic_1, getString(R.string.dialog_title_ble_authentication), getString(R.string.dialog_message_ble_authentication), true, 1, true);

                                        } else {
                                            DialogUtil.showOkDialog(getActivity(), getString(R.string.dialog_title_alert), getString(R.string.dialog_message_ble_connection), getString(R.string.dialog_action_ok), false);

                                        }
                                    }
                                }, 1000);


                            } else {

                                DialogUtil.showOkDialog(getActivity(), getString(R.string.dialog_title_error), getString(R.string.dialog_message_ble_connection), getString(R.string.dialog_action_ok), true);
                            }
                            break;
                        case Constants.STOP:
                            if (mConnGatt != null) {
                                GlobalVariable.bleStatus = 0;
                                mConnGatt.setCharacteristicNotification(characteristic_6, true);
                                BluetoothGattDescriptor descriptor = characteristic_6.getDescriptor(UUID.fromString(BleUuid.DESCRIPTOR_CONFIG_UUID));
                                descriptor.setValue(BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_NOTIFICATION_VALUE);
                                mConnGatt.writeDescriptor(descriptor);
                                new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void run() {
                                        if (GlobalVariable.bleStatus == 2) {
                                            System.out.println("***button click*****" + GlobalVariable.bleStatus);

                                            mChargingConnectionPresenter.startCharging(mConnGatt, characteristic_1, getString(R.string.dialog_title_ble_authentication), getString(R.string.dialog_message_ble_authentication), true, 1, false);

                                        } else if (GlobalVariable.bleStatus == 4) {
                                            mChargingConnectionPresenter.startCharging(mConnGatt, characteristic_1, getString(R.string.dialog_title_ble_authentication), getString(R.string.dialog_message_ble_authentication), true, 1, false);

                                        } else {
                                            DialogUtil.showOkDialog(getActivity(), getString(R.string.dialog_title_alert), getString(R.string.dialog_message_ble_connection), getString(R.string.dialog_action_ok), false);

                                        }
                                    }
                                }, 1000);


                            } else {

                                DialogUtil.showOkDialog(getActivity(), getString(R.string.dialog_title_error), getString(R.string.dialog_message_ble_connection), getString(R.string.dialog_action_ok), true);
                            }
                            break;

                    }
                }
            });

            mButtonStart2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    switch (mButtonStart2.getTag().toString()) {
                        case Constants.BLE_START:
                            if (mConnGatt != null) {
                                GlobalVariable.bleStatus = 0;
                                mConnGatt.setCharacteristicNotification(characteristic_7, true);
                                BluetoothGattDescriptor descriptor = characteristic_7.getDescriptor(UUID.fromString(BleUuid.DESCRIPTOR_CONFIG_UUID));
                                descriptor.setValue(BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_NOTIFICATION_VALUE);
                                mConnGatt.writeDescriptor(descriptor);

                                new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void run() {
                                        if (GlobalVariable.bleStatus == 1) {
                                            System.out.println("***button click*****" + GlobalVariable.bleStatus);

                                            mChargingConnectionPresenter.startCharging(mConnGatt, characteristic_1, getString(R.string.dialog_title_ble_authentication), getString(R.string.dialog_message_ble_authentication), true, 2, true);

                                        } else if (GlobalVariable.bleStatus == 4) {
                                            mChargingConnectionPresenter.startCharging(mConnGatt, characteristic_1, getString(R.string.dialog_title_ble_authentication), getString(R.string.dialog_message_ble_authentication), true, 2, true);

                                        } else {
                                            DialogUtil.showOkDialog(getActivity(), getString(R.string.dialog_title_alert), getString(R.string.dialog_message_ble_connection), getString(R.string.dialog_action_ok), false);

                                        }
                                    }
                                }, 1000);


                            } else {

                                DialogUtil.showOkDialog(getActivity(), getString(R.string.dialog_title_error), getString(R.string.dialog_message_ble_connection), getString(R.string.dialog_action_ok), true);
                            }
                            break;
                        case Constants.STOP:
                            if (mConnGatt != null) {
                                GlobalVariable.bleStatus = 0;
                                mConnGatt.setCharacteristicNotification(characteristic_7, true);
                                BluetoothGattDescriptor descriptor = characteristic_7.getDescriptor(UUID.fromString(BleUuid.DESCRIPTOR_CONFIG_UUID));
                                descriptor.setValue(BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_NOTIFICATION_VALUE);
                                mConnGatt.writeDescriptor(descriptor);

                                new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void run() {
                                        if (GlobalVariable.bleStatus == 2) {
                                            System.out.println("***button click*****" + GlobalVariable.bleStatus);

                                            mChargingConnectionPresenter.startCharging(mConnGatt, characteristic_1, getString(R.string.dialog_title_ble_authentication), getString(R.string.dialog_message_ble_authentication), true, 2, false);

                                        } else if (GlobalVariable.bleStatus == 4) {
                                            mChargingConnectionPresenter.startCharging(mConnGatt, characteristic_1, getString(R.string.dialog_title_ble_authentication), getString(R.string.dialog_message_ble_authentication), true, 2, false);

                                        } else {
                                            DialogUtil.showOkDialog(getActivity(), getString(R.string.dialog_title_alert), getString(R.string.dialog_message_ble_connection), getString(R.string.dialog_action_ok), false);

                                        }
                                    }
                                }, 1000);


                            } else {

                                DialogUtil.showOkDialog(getActivity(), getString(R.string.dialog_title_error), getString(R.string.dialog_message_ble_connection), getString(R.string.dialog_action_ok), true);
                            }

                            break;

                    }
                }
            });

            mButtonStart3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    switch (mButtonStart3.getTag().toString()) {
                        case Constants.BLE_START:
                            if (mConnGatt != null) {
                                GlobalVariable.bleStatus = 0;
                                mConnGatt.setCharacteristicNotification(characteristic_8, true);
                                BluetoothGattDescriptor descriptor = characteristic_8.getDescriptor(UUID.fromString(BleUuid.DESCRIPTOR_CONFIG_UUID));
                                descriptor.setValue(BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_NOTIFICATION_VALUE);
                                mConnGatt.writeDescriptor(descriptor);

                                new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void run() {
                                        if (GlobalVariable.bleStatus == 1) {
                                            System.out.println("***button click*****" + GlobalVariable.bleStatus);

                                            mChargingConnectionPresenter.startCharging(mConnGatt, characteristic_1, getString(R.string.dialog_title_ble_authentication), getString(R.string.dialog_message_ble_authentication), true, 3, true);

                                        } else if (GlobalVariable.bleStatus == 4) {
                                            mChargingConnectionPresenter.startCharging(mConnGatt, characteristic_1, getString(R.string.dialog_title_ble_authentication), getString(R.string.dialog_message_ble_authentication), true, 3, true);

                                        } else {
                                            DialogUtil.showOkDialog(getActivity(), getString(R.string.dialog_title_alert), getString(R.string.dialog_message_ble_connection), getString(R.string.dialog_action_ok), false);

                                        }
                                    }
                                }, 1000);


                            } else {

                                DialogUtil.showOkDialog(getActivity(), getString(R.string.dialog_title_error), getString(R.string.dialog_message_ble_connection), getString(R.string.dialog_action_ok), true);
                            }
                            break;
                        case Constants.STOP:
                            if (mConnGatt != null) {
                                GlobalVariable.bleStatus = 0;
                                mConnGatt.setCharacteristicNotification(characteristic_8, true);
                                BluetoothGattDescriptor descriptor = characteristic_8.getDescriptor(UUID.fromString(BleUuid.DESCRIPTOR_CONFIG_UUID));
                                descriptor.setValue(BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_NOTIFICATION_VALUE);
                                mConnGatt.writeDescriptor(descriptor);

                                new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void run() {
                                        if (GlobalVariable.bleStatus == 2) {


                                            mChargingConnectionPresenter.startCharging(mConnGatt, characteristic_1, getString(R.string.dialog_title_ble_authentication), getString(R.string.dialog_message_ble_authentication), true, 3, false);

                                        } else if (GlobalVariable.bleStatus == 4) {
                                            mChargingConnectionPresenter.startCharging(mConnGatt, characteristic_1, getString(R.string.dialog_title_ble_authentication), getString(R.string.dialog_message_ble_authentication), true, 3, false);

                                        } else {
                                            DialogUtil.showOkDialog(getActivity(), getString(R.string.dialog_title_alert), getString(R.string.dialog_message_ble_connection), getString(R.string.dialog_action_ok), false);

                                        }
                                    }
                                }, 1000);


                            } else {

                                DialogUtil.showOkDialog(getActivity(), getString(R.string.dialog_title_error), getString(R.string.dialog_message_ble_connection), getString(R.string.dialog_action_ok), true);
                            }

                            break;

                    }
                }
            });

        }catch (Exception e){
            DebugLogUtil.log(Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace(), e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please add the code, which have u tried ?